What is the simplest form of a lorentz matrix?
We know for an element in $O(n)$, there are orthonormal basis that make an orthogonal transformation as:
$k$ $1$ s on the diagonal
$l$ $-1$ s on the diagonal
$m $ matrices belonging to $SO(2)$.
I was wondering if there is a structure for the matrices belonging to $O(m,n)$?
